# Fazer com que um projeto com web Api c# retorne um RSS

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Estou precisando fazer com que o meu projeto em rest WEB API retorne RSS ao invez de json ou XML ... gostaria de ver se alguem já conseguiu fazer ?

Comment: Aqui [nesse link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/559378/Implementing-Custom-Media-Formatters-in-ASP-NET-We) tem um projeto completo implementando formatos de mídia customizados.

Comment: Mas RSS é um XML só que formatado de acordo para estar com os dados das "news"

Comment: Achou alguma solução? Poste como resposta para ajudar outras pessoas.

Comment: @bigown eu seguei esse tutorial http://www.strathweb.com/2012/04/rss-atom-mediatypeformatter-for-asp-net-webapi/ estou procurando o projeto mas acho que para retornar somente o rss eu adicionei esse código abaixo no Global.asax  dentro de Application_Start


            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Clear();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Add(new SyndicationFeedFormatter());

Comment: E funcionou para você? Poste como resposta para todos poderem aproveitar. E aceite-a depois.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu consegui resolver com esse tutorial http://www.strathweb.com/2012/04/rss-atom-mediatypeformatter-for-asp-net-webapi/ e adicionando o código abaixo no Global.asax dentro de Application_Start :

GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Clear(); GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Add(new SyndicationFeedFormatter());

O projeto já saiu do ar,mas eu tinha um print do exemplo que eu tinha enviado para o cliente.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]